# Do Azure Web Sites support Http Handler Mappings to custom Extensions?

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I'm trying out running a customer application on Azure Web sites, to see what problems we might be running into. This application uses a number of custom HttpHandlers and web.config handler mappings to these handlers. Unfortunately all of the custom handler requests fail with:

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

The handlers are configured in web.config in  and they work fine on local dev, but I can't get them to work on Azure.

It looks more like a permissions problem, like it's looking for a file on disk, but there's no File restriction mode specified:

```
<add name=".wc_wconnect-module" path="*.wc" verb="*"
    type="Westwind.WebConnection.WebConnectionHandler,WebConnectionModule" 
    preCondition="integratedMode,managedHandler" />
```

Are custom handler mappings supported, or am I just seeing some limitation in terms of file extensions that are not supported? If the latter how can I work around any URL filtering that might be causing this?

Comment: Did you add the handler to the bin folder in your Azure web app?  You can do this using Kudu - https://<yoursitename>.scm.azurewebsites.net.

Comment: Yeah of course - it's there. It works if I map to a 'known extension like axd or ashx but that doesn't work for me in this case.

Comment: @RickStrahl Did you ever find a resolution to this?